# Split Numpy array with missing ranges as delimiters

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

[Graph of points, points that have a green line next to them are missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFf28.png)

I have a numpy array which is essentially a contour, a collection of closed x,y points.

It is formatted in this way:

`main_array = [[0,0],[2,0],[4,0],[6,0],[0,2],[0,4],[0,6],[2,6],[4,6],[6,6],[6,4],[6,2],[6,0]]`

I have another array that states which ranges of values are missing, formatted like this:

`missing_point_ranges = [[[2,6],[4,6]],[[6,4],[6,0]]]`

- `[2,6]` is for `x1`, `y1`
- `[4,6]` is for `x2`, `y2`
- same case with `([6,4],[6,0])`.

Based on those, the objective is to create a new array with multiple dimensions, that uses the missing ranges as delimiters, essentially categorizing the existing points surrounded by missing ranges in separate dimensions.

In this case we would have a new array with two dimensions: One dimension would have only the point `[6,6]` and the other dimension would have the remaining points.

To specify values for output, it would be as this:

`new_array = [[[0,0],[2,0],[4,0],[0,2],[0,4],[0,6]],[6,6]]`

Comment: You could create a mask selection regions of the array based on that. Do you want to select the ranges confined by ```missing_point_ranges```?

Comment: And you could you give an example of expected input and output (with formatting)?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the values within the missing point ranges as delimiters. Input could be as above and output, to make things easier, could be a single array but with multiple dimensions inside it, one for each new sub-contour occurring. To specify values for output, it would be as this: new_array = [[[0,0],[2,0],[4,0],[0,2],[0,4],[0,6],[6,0]],[6,6]]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The ```missing_point_ranges``` are values and not indices? Why is ```startx = [2,6]``` 2d - what does each dimension mean?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes they are values. [2,6] is x1,y1 and [4,6] is x2, y2. Same with 6,4 and 6,0. All the points between those are missing points that should be used as delimiters.

Comment: Ok, so looking at the first region - ```[[2,6], [4,6]]```, you want to select all x values that are between 2 and 4? And all y values that are between 6 and 6?

Comment: The goal is to select all the values are that both between x1 and x2 and y1 and y2 and use them as delimiters, but taking into account all of ranges specified in order to split them correctly.

Comment: Selecting values between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is easy, but how are they used as delimiters? Is it assumed that there will be exactly 2 delimiters for x and y?

Comment: The number of delimiters depends on the number of dimensions the missing_point_ranges array. They could be 2, they could be more. This is why it's tricky. Theoretically, if things were in order, I could iterate and do something like selecting the values between x2,y2 and the x1 and y1 of the next dimension in missing point ranges and assign them as a new dimension in the final array, but I am not sure if this is ideal.